# Semantically-rich markup for discussions in HTML5

Tags: html, semantic-markup

At the moment, I'm marking up a play in HTML5, and trying to use the most semantically-rich markup available. There's plenty of information online about using the [`<dialog>`](http://html5doctor.com/a-little-more-conversation-with-dialog/) tag for this; unfortunately, that [tag has been removed from the draft standard as of September 2009](http://html5doctor.com/september-html5-spec-changes/).

[WHATWG's recommendation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#conversations) for marking up conversations strikes me as somewhat less than ideal from a semantic perspective. Is there another option, or do I just need to look into Microformats/RDFa for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `<p>` tag is semantically most appropriate for this purpose. Every dialogue is a paragraph. Each person gets his/her own paragraph each time he/she speaks. This additional information can be added using `HTML5 data-attributes` or `microformats`.

eg.

```
<p><span class="fname">Praveen</span> : &quot; This is my dialogue. &quot;</p>
<p><span class="fname">Naveen</span> : &quot; and this is mine. &quot;</p>
```

---

PS: ***Using unordered, ordered, definition lists is wrong in this case.***

Answer (score -1):

can't you just use an article? :) that is what comes the closest to what you want. HTML5 is kind of general, they cannot make tags for everything and article just shows the main content :).

Comment: `article` is a sectioning tag. Moreover, each dialogue is not an article. The whole discussion can be wrapped inside an `article` though.